# git status can't find diff-highlight

Tags: git, macos

## Environment

- Mac OSX 10.12.3
- Git version 2.11.1 (installed via Homebrew)

Git had been previously working but today when I executed `git status` in any git directory, I got the following error:

```
sh: /Users/xxx/.zsh/bin/diff-highlight: No such file or directory
```

My $PATH is:

```
/Users/xxx/.composer/vendor/bin:/Documents/Ruby:/usr/texbin:/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims:/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/xxx/.composer/vendor/bin:/Documents/Ruby:/usr/texbin:/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims:/Users/xxx/.fzf/bin
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

Installing/updating to the latest Git version, mostly using proper package management tools like [HOMEBREW](https://brew.sh/), can usually solve problems related to installations and missing scripts/tools.

For some reason my system also did not find *diff-highlight* when issuing Git commands. While double checking it I figured out that I had *diff-highlight* set for my global Git as a pager, and whenever I tried to execute git sub-command (status/show/log) the non found pager wanted to come into play:

```
/ > git log
/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less -r: /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight: No such file or directory
```

After installing Git again via `brew install git` or `brew update git`, it got updated to the latest (2.13.x) version, as well as all the Git tools/files have been reset to its normal place. To obtain where the brew installation puts the scripts/tools and Git commands, files, you can issue:

```
/ > brew info git
git: stable 2.13.0 (bottled), HEAD
Distributed revision control system
https://git-scm.com
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.13.0 (1,463 files, 33.2MB)
```

Under my *~/dotfiles* folder where I store my global settings, amongst others also for Git, I updated the pager setting to the proper location of the *diff-highlight* in the *~/dotfiles/git/gitconfig* file:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/<user_name>/.gitignore_global
    pager = /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.13.0/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less -r
```

For the global settings I am using a customized version of [Jack's Dotfiles](https://github.com/jackfranklin/dotfiles).

Comment: It’s `brew upgrade git` now. Resurrection award!

Comment: Also 
```pager = `brew --prefix git`/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less ``` 
will keep it independent of the git version.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In my .zsh directory, I had removed my subfolder /bin which had the diff-highlight executable. Putting the /bin back solved the problem.